# Conversion failed: when converting the nvarchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I create a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[wsp_Display_Invoice]
     @DOID NVARCHAR(50),
     @brcode INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.Item_Code,
        (B.Description + '-' + B.Product_Code + '(' + D.Brand_Name+ ')') AS Description,
        A.Quantity, B.UOM, A.Rate, A.DOID,
        C.Doc_No, B.Tax_Percentage AS Tax, B.Tax_Percentage AS Tax1,
        F.QuotationID
    FROM 
        DO_T A 
    INNER JOIN 
        inv_Item_Master B ON A.Item_Code = B.Item_Code 
    INNER JOIN 
        DO C ON A.DOID = C.DOID 
    INNER JOIN 
        Inv_Brand D ON D.Brand_ID = B.Brand_ID 
    INNER JOIN 
        Quotation_T F ON F.DOID = A.DOID 
    WHERE 
        A.DOID LIKE '%' + @DOID + '%' 
        AND a.BR_Code = @brcode
END
```

Got a error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '22,23' to data type int.

Comment: Post your table's DDL.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: ok thank u for the information,...i wil folllow it...can u plz help me with that error

Comment: Use [`concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of `+` to avoid accidental implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing an implicit conversion somewhere.  The obvious places are the string concatenation with `+`.  If any of the arguments is a number, then `+` is interpreted as numeric addition -- and you get an error.

Less obvious places are other operations, such as `JOIN` conditions.  If one column is a string and the other a number, then SQL Server attempts to convert the string to a number -- and you can get an error.

So, I would try the following.

Replace:

```
   (B.Description + '-' + B.Product_Code + '(' + D.Brand_Name+ ')') AS Description,
```

with:

```
   (B.Description + '-' + CAST(B.Product_Code as VARCHAR(255)) + '(' + D.Brand_Name+ ')') AS Description,
```

This is only necessary if `Product_Code` is a number.

```
A.DOID LIKE '%' + @DOID + '%'
```

with:

```
CAST(A.DOID as VARCHAR(255)) LIKE '%' + @DOID + '%'
```

This is only necessary of `A.DOID` is a number.

Change the type of `@brcode` to a string.  This is only necessary if `a_BR_CODE` is a number.

If these do not work, you will have to look at the `JOIN` conditions to see if any of them mix types.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that we need to know the data types of the DOID fields in the various table. My guess is that there is a data type mismatch on one of the joins.

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[wsp_Display_Invoice]
     @DOID NVARCHAR(50),
     @brcode INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.Item_Code,
        (B.Description + '-' + B.Product_Code + '(' + D.Brand_Name+ ')') AS Description,
        A.Quantity, B.UOM, A.Rate, A.DOID,
        C.Doc_No, B.Tax_Percentage AS Tax, B.Tax_Percentage AS Tax1,
        F.QuotationID
    FROM 
        DO_T A 
    INNER JOIN 
        inv_Item_Master B ON A.Item_Code = B.Item_Code 
    INNER JOIN 
        DO C ON A.DOID = C.DOID 
    INNER JOIN 
        Inv_Brand D ON D.Brand_ID = B.Brand_ID 
    INNER JOIN 
        Quotation_T F ON F.DOID = A.DOID 
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(varchar(50), A.DOID) LIKE '%' + @DOID + '%' 
        AND a.BR_Code = @brcode
END
```

Comment: Can you please explain **what you did** and **why** ? Don't just dump a pile of code on us and let us wonder what you've changed - and how that would solve the issue ....

Comment: I added the conversion after where (CONVERT(varchar(50), A.DOID) LIKE '%' + @DOID + '%' ) as that is the first place where conversion error comes (although it might be in other places also).

Comment: value  '22,23' relates to which field?